# Storing data in 2D array list from result of a Database query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I am querying a database whose output is User ID and the Tags that this User has used, but the tags are in a single string format and enclosed with <>.

I am using these statements to store results

```
String str1 = insertStmt.getString(1);//User ID
String str2 = insertStmt.getString(2);//String for Tags
```

So the output can be thought of as something like:

```
ID   Tags
1    <Java><SQL>
2    <Battery><Installation>
1    <Installation>
...and so on
```

After this I am processing str2 so as to split and remove <> and storing the tags in an ArrayList.

My major goal is to process this data so that I can have a list of all distinct tags for each User ID. The output should be like:

```
ID  Tags
1   Java,SQL,Installation.....
2   Battery,Installation...
.
.
.
and so on
```

I am having trouble in doing the 2nd processing for output. Basically I am not able to visualize how I should proceed and which data structure I should use to store this association.

Comment: Are you obliged to store tags in this fashion? A normalised design would be MUCH easier to work with

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want a `HashMap<Integer, HashSet<String> >`. This will allow you to store all the unique tags per id.

To insert, you need to check if it contains the id you're inserting with `containsKey( id )`. If not, create a new `HashSet<String>`, insert that, and then add the tag. If the key is there, just use `Add( tag )` to add it.

This is talking about how you store it in Java. In SQL, this is a terrible way to store tags. To normalize, you should have something like a `TagNames` table, with `TagId` and `TagName` columns, with `TagId` as the primary key - this is where the actual tags get defined. Then, saying the table to which tags can be applied is named `Things`, with a primary key of `ThingId`, you'll have a `ThingsTags` table, with columns `ThingId` and `TagId`, both of which reference their respective columns in the other table, to relate the two. I'm not sure how much sense this makes, but I don't feel like making a diagram right now.